# Nest.js only accept fields that are specified in a DTO

Tags: typescript, nestjs, dto, class-validator

I'm currently playing around with Nest.js and have a simple app with a route to register accounts. I created a DTO with a few fields as well as a mongodb schema.
There is exactly one field in the mongodb schema I don't want to let a user modify on creation (=privilege), so I didn't specify that in the DTO.

However, if a user makes a request with the privilege property in the body, it'll still get saved to the DTO and then in the schema.

Is there a way to "cut off" any data from the body that doesn't match the DTO? I'm certain it did tell me once that there was a field it does not recognize, but it doesn't seem to work anymore. I tried to find a class validator or something, but couldn't find anything that fits and I don't really want to check every property myself...

Thanks in advance!

---

from account.service.ts

```
  async register(body: RegisterAccountDto) {
    return new_account.save();
  }
```

from account.controller.ts

```
  @ApiOperation({ summary: 'Register user', description: 'Register a new account' })
  @ApiConsumes('x-www-form-urlencoded')
  @ApiBody({ type: [RegisterAccountDto] })
  @Post('register')
  async register(@Body() body: RegisterAccountDto) {
    return this.accountService.register(body);
  }
```

from account.schema.ts

```
  @Prop({ default: Privilege.USER })
  privilege: Privilege;
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For that purpose, you need to use the validation pipe of nestjs with whitelist property true.

Have a look at it: [NestJs Validation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation)

Goto main.ts

Add Import:

```
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
```

then below line where app is being declared, add this line:

```
app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({
    whitelist: true
  }));
```

Comment: Ah, the whitelist option did the trick! I had the validation pipe embedded, but without any configuration. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @fazlu Is there any way we can do it only for a particular Module and not apply `whitelist` globally?

Comment: @ChiragB use this link to use the UsePipe decorator on a method level in the controller of a module, you will be able to use whitelist for a specific controller method of a specific module by following this: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation#transform-payload-objects